# Can't mine diamond in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried using both iron and diamond pickaxes, but diamonds just go poof into smoke. I'm playing survival, and no - the diamond is not falling into lava. Is there any way to fix this? I'm using version 1.12.2, and the only mods I have are a texture pack (Conquest), Optifine, LiteLoader, and VoxelMap. All these work fine.

Comment: Does the same happen without mods?

Comment: Maybe someone installed a troll mod on your Minecraft version?

Comment: If you're using mods, are you sure they're diamonds?

Comment: I suggest editing the question and including a list of all the mods you do have installed

Comment: I already listed the mods. I'll try turning them off first, one by one, but I can't imagine any of them causing this problem.

Comment: Hmm, seems there were no diamonds and the texture pack mistook gravel for diamonds. Problem solved.

Comment: @Faederwulf Might be good to write this as an answer as another user, using the same texture pack might come across the same issue. You are allowed to answer your own questions and also accept, it is even encouraged :)

Comment: @Fran does he need to be a different user? My impression was that you could answer your own question as yourself if there are no answers in 2 days.

Comment: @RoijanEskor No need to wait for two days! If you have found an answer to your own question, go ahead and write that answer. If it is the one that worked for your personally, you can also accept it -- though I would wait a bit to allow some other people to try their luck answering it. In this case, the OP has found the answer themself. Why not self-answer then? :)

Comment: @RoijanEskor As far as I know there is not waiting period. I can even ask questions and answer them right away if I feel I know something that a lot of others don't and the question hasn't been asked/answered before but is useful. Well,..at least on StackOverflow you can, no idea if different rules apply here.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from Faederwolf in the comments:

> Hmm, seems there were no diamonds and the texture pack mistook gravel for diamonds. Problem solved.

A good way to avoid this is one piece of info given to you by viewing the screen info that includes co-ords, usually accessed via pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>. It also tells you what block you are looking at.